# How to know PagingState has reached last Page?

Tags: spring, cassandra

I am using PagingState to manage pagination from my Cassandra database. Currently when I reach the last page and hit the API again I get to the first page.
How do I know that I have reached the last page or any way to stop the rotate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After executing the query if the object of PagingState obtained from ResultSet is null then it means that there are no pages available anymore.